# Paradox database conversion python

Tags: python, sql, paradox

I am currently working on a project that uses Paradox database. I need to be able to either convert the data to sql automatically after the paradox database has been run or to be able to interact with paradox directly. I cannot seem to find a way to do either of these processes through python or though command prompt on windows.

Everything helps!

Thank you,

Ondeckshooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an ODBC driver available for Paradox. You should be able to use that with pyodbc (https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) to access the Paradox database directly from Python.

Comment: I am reciving an error when attempting to connect to the database. I have posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662123/pyodbc-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified-paradox